# redirect issue in grails

Tags: grails, redirect, controller, view

I am new to grails environment, I am trying to make an application where I want the consumer to fill the form and when the consumer submits he or she will be redirected to the controller 
named new. So that I can show a pop up on it.

```
package mailtest

class SendController {

def index() { }

def send = {
    sendMail{
        to "admin@oneroofcorp.com"
        from params.email
        subject "Requirement Specification Document"
        body "Requirement Specifiction details \n Company Details \n\n Name : ${params.cname} \n Address : ${params.cadd} \n Contact No : ${params.cpn} \n email : ${params.cemail}\n \n Contact Person\n\n Name : ${params.name}\n Phone No : ${params.pn}\n Designation : ${params.designation}\n\n\n Project Domain : ${params.pd}\n About Project : ${params.aproject} \n Goal of Project : ${params.gop}\n Features ${params.feat} \n Desired Audience : ${params.audience}\n Timeline : ${params.tl0}\t${params.tl1} \n Budget : ${params.budget}\n Refrence : ${params.refrence}\n Remarks : ${params.remarks}"
     }
     forward controller: "new", action: "index"
     //redirect(controller:"new",action:"index")
    }
}
```

I tried to redirect the views etc.

Comment: what issue do you have? does it work? or any exception? code looks good

Comment: whenever i click on submit it show sme following errorError 500: Internal Server Error
URI
/MailTest/send/send
Class
javax.mail.internet.AddressException
Message
Missing ']'

Comment: it's mail exception. please add full stacktrace to question

Comment: you should validate the user input

Comment: the actual issue is i am unable to redirect it to other page/view. whenever i try to use the redirect or forward controller function it throws me an error. without redirect or forward controller the program runs properly

Comment: is there any other way to show popup and also send the data to the mail id provided